# Shell Script to Run .jar Works From Terminal but not AppleScript

Tags: java, shell, jar, applescript

I am using a shell script to run a .jar file and input parameters. When I cd into the folder containing the relevant files and call the following line, everything works.

`cat 'prompt.csv' | sh runScript.sh 'WVFO'`

I want to run this from an AppleScript, and when I use the following code, I get an error

```
do shell script "cat 'path_to_file/prompt.csv' | sh path_to_file/runScript.sh 'WVFO'"
```

This is the error being raised:

```
error "Error: Could not find or load main class outputFocalAnalysis.FocalInfoEdge
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: outputFocalAnalysis.FocalInfoEdge" number 1
```

Finally, here is my sh code:

```
echo "First arg: $1"
if [ $1 = "WSO" ]; then
    echo "WSO found"
    java -cp MatrixPath2.0.jar outputFocalAnalysis/FocalInfoVertex
elif [ $1 = "WVFO" ]; then
    echo "Must be WVFO"
    java -cp MatrixPath2.0.jar outputFocalAnalysis/FocalInfoEdge
else    
    echo "Argument 1 Invalid"
fi
```

The folder structure is as follows:
`Project` is the main folder containing `run.scpt` (the AppleScript), `prompt.csv`, `runScript.sh`, and `MatrixPath2.0.jar`.

---

**Edit:**

`path_to_file` is the complete path to that project folder i.e `Users/my_name/Documents/Work/Project/prompt.csv`

Comment: is your jar in the current folder or at `path_to_file` location? you need to set the classpath accordingly

Comment: It is in the current folder. When I do not use the full path for the shell script and csv, I get a `No such file or directory` error. The `path_to_file` location is the current folder as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196349/discussion-between-sidgate-and-taurus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: outputFocalAnalysis.FocalInfoEdge"` says that the jar was not properly set in the classpath. Please try following in your shell script

```
java -cp path_to_file/MatrixPath2.0.jar outputFocalAnalysis/FocalInfoVertex
```